# CAAnimation track progress

Tags: cocoa-touch, cocoa, ios, core-animation

I've been working recently on some animations and it struck me that there is no delegate method of CAAnimation that updates animation progress. I've tried to use a timer and request a transform from a view being transformed (rotated by z axis) but it always returns the same transform.

Is there any way to get the values being updated by CAAnimation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want the details of the current state of the animation of a layer, query `[layer presentationLayer]`. You can access the `transform` property within that object.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, no. However, core animation is time based, so you can always mimic it independently. Also, if you are looking for some discrete precise moments, you can split your animation into a chain and update your state within the `animationDidStop` callback.